# Can comments be moved from an answer to the question?

Tags: support, comments

I mistakenly added a comment to an answer rather than to the [original question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/69513/when-did-the-early-church-begin-and-end-their-twice-weekly-fasts) as I had intended.  Others responded and there are now five comments in the wrong place.

Is there some way to move those comments to be comments on the original question?

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit since all information from it seem to be already covered in the accepted answer. [Generally questions should not contain the answer.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) If you want to request clarification from any answer author, comment on their post. If you have a follow-up question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's... *kinda* possible. There's a tool that'll convert the answer itself to a comment *and move all the comments on that answer* to the question (or another answer) - this is pretty useful when someone, say, posts a request for clarification as an answer, posts an update to their question as an answer, etc.

In this case, it's overkill though; to move 5 comments we'd have to delete and then restore the answer, create an irrelevant comment and move another one, then clean all that up.

Probably best to just... apologize and either delete or re-post your comment. Or make your point in your own answer.

Comment: I'd already expanded the comments into an answer, and mentioned in the comments that they were my mistake.  Moving the comments is obviously neither trivial nor worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with a slight hack. However, as comments are [considered to be transient](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), you shouldn't really bother the mods with this unless absolutely necessary. In your specific case, it's not; the comments are related to the topic being discussed in the answer. I'd just leave it and move on (or if time permits, incorporate the main points in the comments in an answer).

---

**Step 1**: A moderator has to convert the answer into a comment on the original question along with all its comments.

[image]

**Step 2**: They should then *undelete the answer* (as converting an answer into a comment automatically deletes the answer), and the *delete the unwanted comments* on the original question (including the answer which was converted to a comment).

So basically, you need to custom flag (i.e. with the "**in need of moderator intervention**" option) one of your comments for a moderator and ask them nicely to do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

Moderators have the option to convert answers to comments. They can choose to relocate all comments too. However this is only for non-answers and should not be used as a tool to relocate comments.

You could try to [contact](/contact) Stack Exchange and ask them to perform the relocation, but you will probably need to have way more convincing arguments than "I commented on the wrong post".

Also comments are designed to be temporary notes. If there is anything of worth in them, it should be edited into the original post or put into an answer.

The best solution is probably to delete the comments and to repost them on the proper post if necessary. You can also flag the post for moderator attention and ask a moderator to clean up the comments.

---

I see that you have already answered the post and from my point of view your comments and your answer seem quite similar. I would therefore suggest to edit the most important points into your answer and delete your comments.